# Adaptive Cards : Highlighting Dates in Date Input

Tags: adaptive-cards

Hi using adaptive cards on my chatbot ui, i have a Adaptive card of "type": "Input.Date".When the user opens up the date panel, i need to high light few dates based on custom logic. is that something that adaptive cards implementation supports. I have a specific scenario where input.date selection should be used to pre-filter input.time as part of the same card.

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently supported in the property set of the Input Date element

http://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.Date.html

You should request this as a feature on the GitHub site:

https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues